# Display svg within ionic alert

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to make custom [ionic alerts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert) that include an `<svg>` in the message parameter since Ionic states that `message`:

> The main message to be displayed in the alert. `message` can accept either plaintext or HTML as a string. To display characters normally reserved for HTML, they must be escaped. For example `<Ionic>` would become `&lt;Ionic&gt`;

However, when I try the following, no image is shown:

```
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: params.title,
  message: `
    <svg width="27px" height="82px" viewBox="0 0 27 82" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <title>np_exclamation-mark_920809_FDFF25</title>
      <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
      <defs></defs>
      <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <g id="iPad-Portrait" transform="translate(-371.000000, -1116.000000)" fill-rule="nonzero" fill="#FDFF25">
              <g id="np_exclamation-mark_920809_FDFF25" transform="translate(371.000000, 1116.000000)">
                  <path d="M16.648,63.301 C16.0262694,63.0291894 15.3701293,62.8441243 14.698,62.751 C14.1380094,62.6473705 13.5694896,62.5968131 13,62.6 C12.433,62.6 11.882,62.648 11.351,62.75 C10.677918,62.8431906 10.0207959,63.028248 9.398,63.3 C8.332,63.698 7.367,64.35 6.5,65.25 C4.699,67.081 3.8,69.284 3.8,71.85 C3.8,74.417 4.699,76.6 6.5,78.398 C8.3,80.198 10.465,81.101 13,81.101 C15.566,81.101 17.75,80.198 19.55,78.398 C21.351,76.601 22.25,74.418 22.25,71.851 C22.25,69.284 21.351,67.081 19.55,65.249 C18.683,64.351 17.715,63.699 16.648,63.3 L16.648,63.301 Z M25.898,13.148 C26.933,4.418 22.633,0.082 13,0.148 C3.399,0.183 -0.852,4.448 0.25,12.949 L6.852,58.351 L19.3,58.351 L25.898,13.148 Z" id="Shape"></path>
              </g>
          </g>
      </g>
    </svg>`,
  buttons: customButtons
});
alert.present();
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

When I added the escaped version of the `svg`, it loaded it as text, rather than an image!

[image]

Comment: What your're trying to insert in your alert is not text (or message), but innerHTML. I don't think it's possible to do it, but if it were by any chance, you would need to sanitize it in order to make it work. Just a hint if you find a way to inject innerHTML.

If I were you, I would change to modal (ModalController) and create the whole alert myself. It will be faster than hacking AlertController (again, if this is possible at all).

Comment: @elnezah So I tried that first but I couldn't modify the size of the modal for some reason.  It's too big

Comment: Then try just to make the background of your modal transparent and draw a smaller div that will be your alert. I do this creating a class in my `variables.css` (with transparent background) and then applying it to my modal when I create the modal: `modalController.create({cssClass: 'transparent-modal'})`.

Comment: @elnezah great idea!  I'll give that a try

Comment: If it helped you, don't forget to upvote ;-)

Comment: @elnezah I'm really trying to create an overflow that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Ionic alerts support images. You may have to use a Modal or Popover for displaying media. Or maybe change the background using css for the alert and adjust the size and positioning - might get messy. From what I know alerts are not meant to hold images; you could try request it on their Git, maybe they'll form a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular to inject a component dynamically into an arbitrary DOM-slot.

Here is an example I have just built to show a countdown next to the dialog buttons:

Wait until your dialog is present and then ....

```
   this.componentInjector.inject(".alert-wrapper .alert-button:nth-child(2)", CountdownComponent, instance => {
                instance.text = options.okText;
                instance.seconds = options.confirmAfterSeconds;
            });
```

With

```
@Injectable()
export class ComponentInjector {

constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    private app: ApplicationRef
) {

}

async inject<T>(slotSelector: string, componentConstructor: new (...args) => T, configureInstance: (instance: T) => any): Promise<void> {

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentConstructor);

    const slot = document.querySelector(slotSelector);

    const ref = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], slot);

    configureInstance(ref.instance as T);

    this.app.attachView(ref.hostView);

}
```

}

It's not polished yet but seems to work.